# What is app links assistant and how it differs from firebase app indexing?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-app-indexing, firebase-app-indexing

I have read about App links assistant in a newest android studio version 2.3, what is difference between App links assistant and Firebase App indexing?

Comment: Here's an official video explaining and showing you the whole process of using it https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lpaByLW_ctw

Answer (score 2):

**Android Studio 2.3** come up with a new [App Link Assistant](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/app-link-indexing.html) which helps you build and have a consolidated view of your URIs in your app that *makes app content searchable by Google*. As mobile apps become more pervasive, users are looking for relevant information not only from websites but also from apps they have installed. you can enable App Link Assistant and present your Android app as a destination to users through Google Search results. You can make your existing web content discoverable to mobile clients that support App Links. When people click on links to your existing content through supported clients, they can load the content in your app instead of a web view.

*Firebase app indexing is used to index content in your android app* to make searching through the content of application easier and faster. After adding **Android App Links** to your app, you can add Firebase App Indexing code to an activity to get re-engagement to your app from additional Google Search features, including autocomplete suggestions and In Apps search. Learn more about Firebase App Indexing in the [Firebase App Indexing documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-indexing/).

To add Firebase App Indexing to your app, use the [Firebase Assistant](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/firebase.html) in Android Studio and expand the App Indexing section for step-by-step instructions

**References**

Take a breath and go through the well-documented articles.

- How firebase app indexing work - [Link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-indexing/#how_does_it_work)
- Android App Links - [Link](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/heuristic-outcomes-by-ade-oshineye-6a360cc923ad)
- What are App Links? - [Link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lpaByLW_ctw)

Comment: Through  App link assistance or with the help of Firebase linking can I send the user to play store when he clicks on the link and app is not installed in Phone.